# I am getting a compile time error when trying to implement the hateos , It is not showing me the methodOn method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am trying to implement the Hateoas using spring boot.
In my `UserController` class i have used the below code

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public Resource<User> retrieveUser(@PathVariable int id) {
    User user = service.findOne(id);
    Resource<User> resource = new Resource<User>(user);
    ControllerLinkBuilder linkTo=linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).retrieveAllUsers());
```

I am getting a compile time error on line where i am using the - `methodOn()`.
Compiler is not able to find the methodOn using the controller link builder.

I have used the below import to implement hateoas

`import org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*;`

Comment: Do you have the same issue with `linkTo`?

Answer (score 0):

Methods you are using here are static, so to use them you need access using class reference unless you import them using `static import`s. See more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)